# How to get ajax response from other domain?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, cross-domain, yql

Except YQL ,Is there any way to get ajax's response and data from other domain without modifying server side's code?

YQL has limit (1000 calls per hour) for free user , but most of people said it's actually less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you mean by *"without modifying server side's code"* is not modifying the server of the data source, then you can have your own proxy server (basically making your own YQL server) to read the remote data. This is possible because the server-side is not bound to the Same-Origin Policy.

So you can AJAX your server, then let your server read the remote server using some form of `wget`, `curl` or `fopen`, and return what was retrieved:

```
Remote server <- fopen, curl or wget -> your server <- AJAX -> browser
```

Comment: thanks , I know this method you said.  but hopefully , I won't need to modify my or data server side's code . is there other free query server like YQL?

Comment: @George it's better you'd make one on your own server. An advantage to that is you can use AJAX to query your server (same domain), plus you have total control over it (no query limits etc.)

Comment: you're right. it's mush easier . However, I just found I can use yql.multi function to download a lot of data within one call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the iframe receiver pattern. It's an old technique. See [Secure Cross-Domain Communication in the Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735305.aspx) by Danny Thorpe on MSDN. You dont have to use JSONP but still can make cross-domain calls

Comment: thanks for your reply . I think this solution is just like html5 postMessage method . Though postMessage cannot support in old browsers....

Answer (score 1):

You can use a HTML 5 feature which is postMessage to do cross domain calls. Again it is not supported in all the browsers. Look at the following link for implementation: 
[Cross domain call using postMessage](http://somethingcliche.com/2010/05/12/cross-domain-messages-with-postmessage/)

Comment: Thanks for your sharing !!!! It can solves my current problem while communicating between different iframes!!