# Error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :” in ajax for my Odata webservice

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery-mobile, jsonp

I have below code in my .js but when I execute getting error as Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :” in javascript console of Google chrome. when I click on it to show errorneous row I can see my data in JSON format.

below is code.

```
try {
  $.ajax({
  url: "http://X.X.X.X:8000/HW_348671/HW_348671/oppo.xsodata/oppo1?$format=json",
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp',

  crossDomain: true,

  error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Ajax Call Error');
                },
      success: function (data) { alert("bingo"); }
});
}
 catch(error){
   alert("Catch Error-"+error);
 }
});  
});
```

I have setup Odata service on database table of SAP HANA & this URL works fine when I put it in browser but not working from my .js file.

Used JSONP to avoid  Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.

am I doing something wrong in above code ?

Thanks
Regards,
Harshawardhan.

Comment: You can't just use JSONP. The server has to support it, and your request must be formatted with a callback function.

Comment: ohh.Thanks for quick reply. Then if I have to request the present URL avoid access-control-allow-origin error then what would be the solution?

Comment: You could have your server request the data, then pass the data on to your client.

Comment: Actually I don't think I can do anything on server side.. I just has this URL & want to display the requested data on webpage. Is there any solution which keeps server out of purview..

Comment: Can you check if the server is returning valid JSON?

Comment: Mike, If I append ?callback=? to my URL (http://10.243.115.95:8000/HW_348671/HW_348671/oppo.xsodata/oppo1?$format=json?callback=?) & put it in browser it gives msg as "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below".  what does this signify ?

Comment: yes. server is returning valid JSON. i.e if i remove ?callback=? from above URL

Comment: I am not able to use JSON bacaz of access-control-allow-origin error. Hence struggling with JSONP

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get ajax response from other domain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278545/how-to-get-ajax-response-from-other-domain)